# SimpleSaml PHP custom identification page

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I instal [simpleSamlPHP](https://simplesamlphp.org/) Service provider and Identity provider side. The connection work but each time the user have to pass by this page of the identityProvider for autentificate him :
[image]

How can i do for modify this page or remplace it by my own connection page without change the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [theming the user interface](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-theming) on the SimpleSaml website. Per that page

> In SimpleSAMLphp every part that needs to interact with the user by
>   using a web page, uses templates to present the XHTML. SimpleSAMLphp
>   comes with a default set of templates that presents a anonymous look.
>
> You may create your own theme, where you add one or more template
>   files that will override the default ones. This document explains how
>   to achieve that.